# copy few files from a directory that are specified in a text file (linux)

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory called images
and it contains many images.
For example:

```
images/
    imag001.png
    imag002.png
    imag003.png
    imag004.png
```

And I have a text file that has the files that I want to copy somewhere else. Say the test.txt file has

```
img001.png
img003.png
```

How do I copy the files specified in test.txt from the images folder to some other place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many solutions to this problem. I would do it by using xargs:

```
cd images/
cat path/to/test.txt | xargs -I FILES cp FILES path/to/dest/
```

Comment: how to do this recursively

Answer (score 1):

try this one-liner under your `images` directory:

```
awk '{print "cp "$0" /target/path"}' test.txt|sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the bash shell you can do:

```
for image in $(cat copylist.txt); do
    cp $image destination
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
while IFS= read -r image_filename ; do
    cp images/"$image_filename" some_other_place/
done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cat copylist.txt  | xargs -n1 -I %  echo cp   % destination/.
 # remove echo after testing
```